# shape plan design

Tags: pcb, voltage-regulator, design

I am a beginner in routing, I have sensitive signals on my PCB. I did the following routing as a first provisional but they asked me to make plane shapes at the voltage regulator. but i cant figure out how i should make this shape plane. and what is his role
[image]

I have 3 regulator (2: 100v 50mA and 1: 15v 21mA)
[image]

Comment: Most PCB CAD programs have a "polygon pour" or "area fill" command to make copper areas of random shapes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't tell you how you do the plane shapes, because you did not tell us which layout program you are using.

But I can answer your question regarding what's the role of a plane shape. A plane shape has multiple use-cases:

1. It acts as a electromagnetic shield for the circuit (equivalent to a shield around a cable). So it reduces noise on your circuit.
2. Together with the supply traces, it acts as a high frequency capacitor. This reduces very high frequency noise.
3. It conducts the heat away from an IC and radiates that head to the ambient surroundings. So it cools down the ICs which produce a lot of heat.